# Amazon Web Services in Africa

Tags: google-app-engine, azure, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I am researching the feasibility of developing an sms driven mobile service in Africa . Has anyone used AWS/Azure/Google App Engine cloud based services in Africa ? (Ghana to be more specific). What sort of issues did you run into? Is latency a big deal if I were shooting for near realtime notification operation? Data will be going from a user's phone via sms to the cloud and back down again to another server via an API. I need to weigh the pros and cons of having a local server vs using a cloud based service.

Answer (score 0):

I did a lil research on Amazon web services. They don't support Africa YET